Where is the setSelected(_:animated:) in ASCellNode when using AsyncDisplayKit/Texture?
I am using AsyncDisplayKit/Texture in my iOS app.
A typical subclass of UITableViewCell offers the following 2 functions which can be overridden:
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    <#code#>
}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    <#code#>
}

However, a subclass of ASCellNode doesn't seem to offer a similar function with the animated parameter. It only has the following:
override var isHighlighted: Bool {...}

override var isSelected: Bool {...}

Any idea why? How can I pass an animated parameter when selecting/highlighting? I only want to animate it when done via user interaction. I don't want to animate it otherwise.
Note that the ASTableNode does provide the function:
tableNode.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)

but the animated part seems to get lost somewhere.
